# how to detect screen mirroring

Tags: android, events, screen, mirroring

I have been wondering if there is any way in the android API (or any other lib/framework) that can help me to detect if my device screen is mirrored using WiDi,Miracast or MHL or basically any other technique for mirroring your screen.

Br,
Inx

Comment: Have you any solutions?

Comment: Have you found a way to achieve it? It would be helpful if you share it. Thanks.

Comment: @Harco soultion  https://stackoverflow.com/a/64876594/11390822

Answer (score 0):

You may navigate through the list of all device display and get flags on each for finding one with, maybe, VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR ? Not sure but a few trys should allow you to figure out which ones will do it.

cf: [DisplayManager](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiptsrT45HRAhUMrI8KHQ52Bk8QFggiMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fhardware%2Fdisplay%2FDisplayManager.html&usg=AFQjCNGBmZvLbpWybveJU54nyIofojPC_A&sig2=2N2qf5Aa-LIp7gGoeoqSTQ) and [VirtualDisplay](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiptsrT45HRAhUMrI8KHQ52Bk8QFggqMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Freference%2Fandroid%2Fhardware%2Fdisplay%2FVirtualDisplay.html&usg=AFQjCNE7yL13hwpHaBjbkMzbfVRPGdZ0Kg&sig2=dZf4wqtY0MEDnErQs8vroA) documentation

Answer (score 0):

Since API level 16 (Android 4.1, released in 2012 so rather new when the question was asked) Android has had `MediaRouter` API. Adding callback for `ROUTE_TYPE_LIVE_VIDEO` subscribes `MediaRouter.Callback.onRoutePresentationDisplayChanged` to be called when external display is connected or disconnected. If the app has sound, other option is to track routed output. The output types `TYPE_HDMI` and `TYPE_REMOTE_SUBMIX` are used for external display.

Answer (score -1):

You can't **detect** but you can **remove functionality** which mirrors.
No software can mirror if **developer option** is **disabled**. 
This code will tell whether android can mirror or not.

```java
int CanMirror = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED , 0);
//returns 1 if can mirror
//returns 0 if can't mirror
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63971764/11390822

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you simply want to disable screenshots and such, you can use `FLAG_SECURE`.

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE
- http://www.vogella.com/code/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/SecureWindowActivity.html

Comment: well.. the thing Im trying to achieve is to detect if my current device also is mirroring its screen to a tv or a projector or any other monitor/screen.

Comment: this won't prevent mirrors