# Programatically enable/disable screen mirroring in Android. [root]

Tags: android, casting, screen, mirror

I'm trying to develop an Android app which detects if screen mirroring is currently ON and enables/disables this functionality.

Is there any API I can use in order to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to protect your app from screen mirroring? If thats the case have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889685/how-to-detect-screen-mirroring).

Comment: Honestly I don't know which is the purpose of this action. I've been asked if I could do this and in how much time. I know there's an option in some device in which you can enable/disable this option. But I've not been able to find documentation about this. I'll have a look at your link ;)

Comment: @Aldridge1991 long time but will be helpful for new ones: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64876664/11390822

Answer (score 1):

You can **remove functionality** which mirrors.
No software can mirror if **developer option** is **disabled**. 
This code will tell whether android can mirror or not.

```java
int CanMirror = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED , 0);
//returns 1 if can mirror
//returns 0 if can't mirror
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63971764/11390822