# Detect screen mirroring using xamarin.forms.android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, display-manager, android-virtualdisplay

I want to **detect android screen mirroring** to pc.
I am currently coding in **c# Xamarin Forms Android**.

### What I have done

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41330788/11390822) someone recommended to use **DisplayManager** and **VirtualDisplay** documentation. But I don't know how to achieve that in code.

[Here](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-mstg/issues/1145#issuecomment-467688740) someone recommended to check DisplayManager.getDisplays(), and see if it's >1. Again not working to detect vysor I tried with code.

Comment: Check `ProjectMediaManager`and `ProjectMedia` classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got the working answer.
**Android mirrors like vysor can't mirror without having developer options enabled.**
To check whether mirror can be run, check this code below:

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/31582092/11390822

var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
var resolver = context.ApplicationContext.ContentResolver;
if (Settings.Secure.GetInt(resolver, Settings.Global.DevelopmentSettingsEnabled, 0) == 1)
{
//Developer options enabled
//Mean vysor can mirror
}
else
{
//Developer options disabled
//Mean vysor can't mirror now
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to do so in Android.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44544931/how-to-programmatically-detect-if-any-screen-recording-process-app-is-running-in)

The closest you could get is by using [FlagSecure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_SECURE) to prevent screenshots.

Comment: Please check the answer I have referenced

Comment: We both have new thing to [learn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63971764/11390822).